# Is there any way to get Resolve Object of browser without passing the Intent URI as Constructer?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

In order to get the `ResolveInfo` object of the browser, we can pass the Intent like below

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"));
```

then we have to pass this intent like this to get `ResolveInfo` Object ,

```
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browserIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

Is there any way to get browser Resolveinfo object without passing the URI as a Second Constructor, Thanks

Comment: Your `Intent` is not limited to "the browser". You do not have to include a `Uri` as the second parameter to the `Intent` constructor, but then you may not get the results that you want.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your response, the things is using URI is doesn't matter for me, but because of the current situation, I blocked in the implementation, I don't want to use the URI as a second parameter for Intent  constructor ,So I  want to found a way, please suggest me any other filter methods like getting list of objects then filter from the list, anything is fine, but no URI as a Second constructor, please help me